# Scaling word-wrapped text to fit a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with *word-wrapped* text inside. I would like the text to be scaled up to the maximum size that still fits the div without overflowing. How can I achieve that?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#hugetext {width: 250px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid blue; overflow-wrap: break-word;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hugetext">This text shall be so huge that it fills the entire div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On the left is how it looks like, on the right how I would like it to look like:
[image]

I would prefer a pure HTML+CSS solution but if this requires JavaScript then I will accept it.

Comment: There are a bunch of libraries out there. Will this do? https://www.npmjs.com/package/textfit

Comment: It does not sound like that would work with word wrapping to maximise the size.